# NSArray with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to convert a number from an Array to String.

```
NSArray* numberArray = @[@1,@2,@3];
```

I am using `NSNumberFormatter` like this example:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
NSString* numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 100]];
```

How i can convert a number from my Array to string by using NSNumberFormatter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString * convertedNumber = [formatter stringForObjectValue: numberArray[0]]; // convert the first number of your array
```

Answer (score 0):

Coverting a `NSNumber` inside an `NSArray` is no more different than converting your individual `NSNumber`.

So, this is how it will look like with your code:

```
NSArray *numberArray = @[@1,@2,@3];
NSNumber *firstNumber = numberArray[0];
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:firstNumber];
```

However, you get a direct method `stringValue` from `NSNumber` which you can utilize like this:

```
NSArray *numberArray = @[@1,@2,@3];
NSNumber *firstNumber = numberArray[0];
NSString *numberString = firstNumber.stringValue;
```

PS: The example above shows the first item in array. You can fetch any item base on your need and rest of the code shall remain same.